# will_paginate followers in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I'm trying to do paginate for followers.

How I can use will_paginate here?

This code doesn't work

```
@followers = @user.followers(User).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 15)
```

Here I'm trying to do it

```
def followers
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
  @followers = @user.followers(User)
end
```

Comment: Is ```@user.followers(User)``` a instance method?

Comment: I'm using socialization gem https://github.com/cmer/socialization

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@followers = @user.followers.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 15)
```

Comment: it gives an error
wrong number of arguments (0 for 1..2)